# How to convert yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss [+-] hh:mm to timestamp yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss in Datastge?

Tags: etl, datastage

How to convert yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss [+-] hh:mm to timestamp yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss in Datastge?

Eg:

From

2021-01-26T01:07:00-05:00

To
2021-01-26 01:07:00

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the original data type you could use string functions
and [StringToTimestamp](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZJPZ_11.7.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.ds.parjob.dev.doc/topics/r_deeref_Type_Conversion_Functions.html)
Otherwise you could check out [Date and Time functions](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZJPZ_11.7.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.ds.parjob.dev.doc/topics/r_deeref_Date_and_Time_Functions.html) as well.

Answer (score 0):

If the data type is string, convert the "T" to a space " " using Convert() function.
Use Left() function to get rid of the "+/-  hh:mm".
If the data type is timestamp, do nothing until you need to display it; the internal representation of a timestamp does not have a "T" in it.  If you're writing it to a text file, for example, use TimestampToString() function to specify your desired format, although the default format may well suit your need.